# Why does journalctl's json output not print the entire exception stack trace?

Tags: json, journal

When I run journalctl with output **cat** it prints the entire exception stack trace as expected.
Running journalctl with output **json** and it skips the first line:

```
[root@doc-test-node01 splunk]# journalctl -f -o cat | grep undertow

13:35:31,858 ERROR [io.undertow.request] [bruker=01026300394 korrId=826gg6c45 kallId=826y7otah] (default task-62) Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ POST /startlan-esoknad/soknader/}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.close(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:245)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.closeAndDrainRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:602)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.close(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:87)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.endExchange(HttpServerExchange.java:1444)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:213)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
```

When I run `journalctl -f -o json-pretty | grep undertow` then journalctl skips the first line:

```
[root@doc-test-node01 splunk]# journalctl -f -o json-pretty | grep undertow

        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:171)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.close(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:245)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.closeAndDrainRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:602)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.close(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:87)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.endExchange(HttpServerExchange.java:1444)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:213)",
        "MESSAGE" : "\u0009at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)",
```

It also skips the first line with output json and json-sse.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that I shouldn't grep. journalctl can't create json of the first line and prints instead numbers meaning that the message is present:

```
"MESSAGE" : [ 27, 91, 48, ...
```